# Matrix tranformation, how to

Tags: linear-algebra

How do we move an object to another place using a matrix transformation?

I've looked at the net, and it all seems to be scalings, reflections, rotations, .... so it it not possible to move an object to a different location? Why?

Edit: The object is from start located at the origin.

Comment: Matrices represent [linear transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map).  You're looking for [affine transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation).

Comment: Note that through homogeneous coordinates, affine transformations can be represented using matrices.

Comment: So imagine a square that has none of its vertices in the origin, but it does cross the origion (so the origin lies on one of the lines connecting the dots)... will an appropiate linear transformation move this square so it does not touch the origin?

Comment: vectors pointing to vertices.

Comment: All right, but due to your question about how I defined the square, does that mean we can transform an object by tranforming the infinite amount of points that make up that object? How would that work out?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to think of this is that you cannot "move" the origin. Here's why:

A linear transformation $T$ must satisfy the following: $T(v_1+v_2)=T(v_1)+T(v_2)$. If our transformation moves the origin, $T(\vec{0}) \neq \vec{0}$, then we have $T(v_1)=T(v_1 + \vec{0})=T(v_1)+T(\vec{0})=T(v_1) + \vec{b} \neq T(v_1)$ for some $\vec{b} \neq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your "object" is just an atom, positioned at the origin ${\bf 0}=(0,0,0)$. If you want to move it to some other place ${\bf p}=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$, just do it, and then it's there. Maybe you want to do this in physical time $0\leq t\leq1$ and along a straight line. Then you can think of a parametric representation
$$t\mapsto{\bf x}(t):=t{\bf p}=(tp_1,tp_2,tp_3)\qquad(0\leq t\leq1)\ ,$$
or with more subtle acceleration and deceleration, like so:
$$t\mapsto{1-\cos t\over 2}{\bf p}\qquad(0\leq t\leq\pi)\ .$$
No matrices here. Why? Because matrices come into play when you want to move not just a single point mass, but *each and every point of space*. A map that affects all of space, and thereby your atom at ${\bf 0}$ in the desired way, is$$T:\quad{\bf x}\mapsto{\bf x}+{\bf p}\qquad({\bf x}\in{\mathbb R}^3)\ .$$
This map translates every point by the same vector ${\bf p}$. Still no matrix in sight. You will need a matrix when the space map $T$ involves, apart from a translation, also a rotation or an affine stretching of all of space. To set up such a map a lot of additional data is needed, but none such is present in your story.